# How to find the Element based on a Selection

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario is Based on selecting a value in dropdown then it will display either Textbox/Dropdown/MultiselectDD. I used if else if statements with IsDisplayed function and tried boolean but it was very slow to find the element. takes atleast 1 min to find.

Is there any other option to find the element based on the selection as quick.

Thanks in advance. Code for your reference

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(String element) 
{
   try {
       driver.findElement(parser.getObjLocator(element));
       return true;
   } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Using if else if

```
if(driver.findElement(parser.getObjLocator("DD")).isDisplayed())
{
    Select ddslectdid= new Select(driver.findElement(
        parser.getObjLocator("DD"))
    );
    ddslectdid.selectByVisibleText("XYZ");
}
else if(driver.findElement(parser.getObjLocator("DateDD1SelectedId")).IsDisplayed())
{
    Select ddscondn = new Select(driver.findElement(
        parser.getObjLocator("DateDD1SelectedId"))
    );  
    ddscondn.selectByVisibleText("ABC");
}
else if(driver.findElement(parser.getObjLocator("DsgnDD")).IsDisplayed())
{
    driver.findElement(parser.getObjLocator("DsgnDD")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("cst-searchinput")).sendKeys("Test");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(
        By.xpath(".//*[@id='Xpth']/div/div/span/div/div/div/ul/li[2]")
    ).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("No Element Displays");
}
```

Comment: can you show your work ?

Comment: Post a code example so we can help fix and benchmark your specific problem. Also if you can provide the website that can help too.

Comment: done @ChickenFeet

Comment: what is parse.getObjLocator()?

Comment: Look into using `page_source()` function to retrieve the html as a `String`. If each drop down has a unique identifier than you can just search for that substring within the `String` using `page_src.contains(uniqueID1)`. String comparisons are quick and you only need to call `page_source()` once.

Comment: @ChickenFeet that was method used to locate elements in properties file. I'll try the page source snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(String element)
{
    try {
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        return ele.isDisplayed();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Try this block.